# Splash Animation on Icon Button is always behind the Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

i'm getting a bug where button click animation always show behind the stack i.e behind the bottomNavigationBar

```
bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(...),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(...),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(...),
            // Imitate an invisible icon
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 0),
              title: const Text(''),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          fixedColor: Colors.indigo,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          iconSize: 24,
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 32.0,
          top: 8.5,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: IconButton(
              splashColor: Colors.green,
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
```

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGvIx.gif)

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work:

```
MaterialButton(
  height: 50,
  shape: const CircleBorder(),
  onPressed: () => {},
  child: const Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
),
```

source:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30658#issuecomment-958890529

Answer (score 0):

wrap your icon button with the Material widget

```
Material(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
  child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        radius: 25,
        onTap: ()=>Navigator.pop(context),
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        highlightColor: Colors.grey,
        child: Container(
          width: 34,
          height: 34,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colours.colorPrimary,
            size: 24,
          ),
        ),
      ))
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [
    // ... other images
    Positioned(
      right: -8,
      bottom: -8,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 24, height: 24),
              splashRadius: 20,
              icon: Container(
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  shape: OvalBorder(side: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.black)),
                ),
                child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.photo, size: 15)),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```